# What Big O is this equation?

Tags: algorithm, equation

I am trying to find the Big O of this equation.

```
n^2*2^(2n+1)
```

I know that n^2 is smaller than the other part but I don't know what Big O value this would be. Its not O(n^2) obviously and I don't think 2^(2n+1) can be simplified in any way.

If someone could help that'd be great.

Comment: Big O notation is about algorithms, not equations.

Comment: @Sobrique Big O notation is about the growth of functions.  It's about algorithms in as much as a function gives the numbers of steps of an algorithm.  But yes, it's not about equations.

Comment: @EvanBechtol No, the `2^(2n)` would dwarf even `n^100`.

Comment: @ah! I misread the problem

Comment: Sorry I understand it's about algorithms. That's an equation found from an algorithm so I just said equation to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

`n^2 * 2^(2 * n + 1) = n^2 * 2^(2 * n) * 2 = O(n^2 * 2^(2 * n))`. It cannot be simplified further.

Comment: one can simplify a bit: n^2 * 4^n